# Why I cannot see all the environments listed in PowerApps but can see in Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

I have Dataverse of Team and I am creating a Power App specifically for that team.

The development for that I am doing in Microsoft Teams application. But if I want to in my own PowerApp application in the browser I am not able to see my dataverse environment.

But if I navigate to Power Automate app in the browser I could see all list of environments.

[image]

Comment: Could you please navigate to admin center(https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/environments) and check if you are able to see the environment details there?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, yeah I can see there

Comment: We are able to repro the issue and we have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any update